# java - what happened to the serialize method on RawMessage

Tags: java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

serialize() method is in java doc but missing in the implementation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49137/java---what-happened-to-the-serialize-method-on-rawmessage/) by [antoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/3343/antoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the confusion - I was looking at older example code. An an to date example is here
http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/test/java/org/ros/internal/message/MessageSerializationTest.java?r=c472d77034653d38e0ed9b7689bb08e632e87d22

---

Originally posted by [antoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/3343/antoine/) with karma: 26 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0